# Undefined index in php (_SESSION['id'] and ['user'])

Tags: php, undefined-index

I'm new to php and I'm following a tutorial to make a login panel. It works fine on the demo website but when I download the code and run on my machine, 5 notices popped up. They all look like: "Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\demo.php on line 24".

From other programming experiences I think that these means I didn't define the variables before using them. However, these variables seem to be existing in the system (from what I understand reading other questions >-<).

I attached my code below and marked the undefined index on the right. Can anyone help me explain what's wrong with the code and how can I solve it? Thanks a lot!

```
<?php
session_name('Login');
session_start();

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')                                     //undefined submit
{
    $err = array();

    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,user FROM writers WHERE user='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['user'])
        {       
                    $_SESSION['user']=$row['user'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            // Store some data in the session
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: demo.php");
    exit;
}
$script = '';

if($_SESSION['msg'])
{
    // The script below shows the sliding panel on page load
    ... 
}
?>

<head>
    ......
</head>

<body>   
<!-- Panel -->
<div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
        <?php   
            if(!$_SESSION['id']):                     //undefined id
            ?>

            <div class="left">
                <form class="clearfix" action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Writer Login</h1>
                    <?php
                        if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err'])      //undefined login-err
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    //Login form
                </form>
            </div>

            <?php
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /login -->  

    <!-- The tab on top --> 
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ? $_SESSION['user'] : 'Guest';?>!</li>                      //undefined user
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li id="toggle">                            
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['id']?'Open Panel':'Log In';?></a>                             //undefined id
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Close Panel</a>         
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- / top -->

</div> <!--panel -->
```

Sorry for the long code! I really not sure which ones will be relevant to the problem and do not dare to delete more. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Please take some time and read about the dangers associated with using the mysql_* extension in PHP (i.e. it's really old and insecure, not to mention deprecated). It's definitely worth the effort to learn how to use PDO or MySQLi instead. On a related note, your code is currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You can read about that here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thanks jdp! I also found that the code is deprecated when I add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if that variable exists *before* you use it. You would use `isset()` for that:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Login')
```

If you're just checking to see if the form was submitted you could just check to see if the page was request via `POST` instead:

```
if('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
```

Comment: Thanks John! But do I need to check for every variables? I thought variables like `$_SESSION['id']` or `$_SESSION['user']` do not need to be checked before using them?

Comment: Unless you know the variable is set when you are trying to use it, you must check for it before you do use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also put `@` in front of your array references that can be null, for example:

```
if(@$_POST['submit']=='Login')
```

This will supress the warning

Comment: Please don't suggest this. Yes, it suppresses the error messages, but they're there for a reason - you should fix the code that's generating the errors rather than hiding them.

Comment: For array references it's fine IMO.  Just don't use it for any function or non-trivial code.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I will try to use this carefully =))